# Python - SSL - wrong version number

Tags: python, sockets, ssl, pyopenssl

This will probably be just another unsolved thread but i'll fill in some info anyway.

I can't get my SSL wrapping together not even for a second.
Any ideas to what i'm doing wrong with my wrap_socket() and do_handshake()?

The key files appear to be 100% perfect, and i've tried with AND without the .recv() before the handshake.
That just generates these depending on where i put the recv():

> SSL3_GET_CLIENT_HELLO:wrong version number
>
> SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

```
class Server():
    def __init__(self, listen = '', port = 8080, ssl = False):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.bind((listen, port))
        self.sock.listen(5)

    def accept(self):
        newsocket, fromaddr = self.sock.accept()
        newsocket.recv(32)
        newsocket.setblocking(0)
        sslsock = ssl.wrap_socket(newsocket,
                                    server_side=True,
                                    certfile="./kernel/sock/server.crt",
                                    keyfile="./kernel/sock/server.key",
                                    cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                                    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1,
                                    do_handshake_on_connect=False,
                                    suppress_ragged_eofs=True)
        sslsock.do_handshake()
        return sslsock, fromaddr
```

For the record, if it's not obvious or i'm wrong, it's the handshake that fails :)

I modified the code a bit, trying SSLv3 and also change the position of the wrapping a bit:

```
import socket, ssl, time, select

class Server():
    def __init__(self, listen = '', port = 443, ssl = False):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.bind((listen, port))
        self.sock.listen(5)

    def accept(self):
        self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                                    server_side=True,
                                    certfile="./kernel/sock/server.crt",
                                    keyfile="./kernel/sock/server.key",
                                    cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                                    ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3,
                                    do_handshake_on_connect=False,
                                    suppress_ragged_eofs=True)

        newsocket, fromaddr = self.sock.accept()

        print [newsocket.recv(32)]
        newsocket.setblocking(False)
        newsocket.do_handshake()

        return newsocket, fromaddr

s = Server()
ns, na = s.accept()
print ns.recv(1024)
```

Now i get with the newsocket.recv(32):

> ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:1331: error:140940E5:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:ssl handshake failure

and without:

> ssl.SSLError: [Errno 2] _ssl.c:490: The operation did not complete (read)

Also: **i refuse to use Twisted**

Scaling things down:

```
import socket, ssl, time, select
from OpenSSL import SSL

class Server():
    def __init__(self, listen = '', port = 443, ssl = False):
        ctx = SSL.Context(SSL.SSLv23_METHOD)
        ctx.use_privatekey_file("server.pem")
        ctx.use_certificate_file("server.pem")
        self.sock = SSL.Connection(ctx, socket.socket())

        self.sock.bind((listen, port))
        self.sock.listen(5)

    def accept(self):
        newsocket, fromaddr = self.sock.accept()
        return newsocket, fromaddr

s = Server()
ns, na = s.accept()
print ns.recv(1024)
```

This works just as good as the "native" ssl library.
However now i get this error:

> OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'SSL23_READ', 'ssl handshake failure')]

---

This is where i'm at now:

```
import socket, ssl, time #, select

class Server():
    def __init__(self, listen = '', port = 443, ssl = False):
        self.sock = socket.socket()
        self.sock.bind((listen, port))
        self.sock.listen(5)

    def accept(self):
        self.ssl_sock = None
        while not self.ssl_sock:
            self.ssl_sock = ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock,
                server_side=True,
                certfile=r"C:\moo.pem",
                keyfile=r"C:\moo.key",
                cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE,
                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

        newsocket, fromaddr = self.ssl_sock.accept()

        print([newsocket.recv()])

        return newsocket, fromaddr

s = Server()
ns, na = s.accept()
print(ns.recv(1024))
```

This works "prefectly" in Firefox, but **NOT** in Google Chrome.
Why? what's the difference? -.-

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't know Python at all to tell you if you have a problem in your code.
The error though is clear. The client supports `SSLv3` and your server only `TLSv1`.
So you should enable support for `SSLv3` or upgrade your client.

This line seems to be the problem:`ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1`. Perhaps you can also add `SSLv3` here?

Update:
I see that you have problem between browsers. See if `SSLv3` is enabled in Crome.
In IE for example this is under `Internet Options`-> `Advanced Tab`.
Something similar should be in Chrome. Disable `SSv3` and enable `TLSv1` instead

Comment: **SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number** WITH the recv() before the handshake is made, and without it i get **_ssl.c:490: The operation did not complete (read)**

Comment: Using **ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv3,**

Comment: Removing SSLv3 works, in FireFox.
SSLv3 is older then TLSv1 so i'd rather stick with TLSv1

Comment: There should be a native way to enable SSL from a socket without having to mess around with browser settings.
You can't go around the world changing peoples browsers just because of your website, just as an example.

Comment: Depends.You can either support both SSLv23 and TLSv1 or drop the weak protocols in favor of TLSv1.If your security requirements are strong, it is not a problem to specify to the "client side" that there can be connectivity issues if the latest TLS is not enabled

Comment: SSLv23 does not mean SSL 2 and SSL 3. It specifically means all supported protocols.