# Python SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER (_ssl.c:590) using urllib with a proxy

Tags: python, ssl, proxy, urllib

This code used to run flawlessly. I haven't changed anything but tried using it from a different location, behind a proxy, and I get this error:

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:590)
```

Here's where it fails:

```
gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
data = urllib.urlopen("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/genre=" + str(category) + "/json", "download.txt", context = gcontext).read()
```

I immediately thought that the problem might come from the proxy I'm using, but don't know how to tell python to use that proxy as well. The solutions in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9963621/python-ssl-wrong-version-number) did not help me (same error).

And here's the full traceback:

```
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Nathan\App_Finder_2.0.1.py in <module>()
     15     print "Checking category " + str(categoryCounter) + " of " + "23..." # progress
     16     print "Opening iTunes RSS feed for top 50 English apps in category " + str(categoryCounter) + " of " + "23..." # progress
---> 17     data = urllib.urlopen("https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topfreeapplications/limit=50/genre=" + str(category) + "/json", "download.txt", context = gcontext).read() # Open data from iTunes RSS Feed. Genre = category, in English
     18     d = json.loads(data) # Load data
     19 

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\urllib.pyc in urlopen(url, data, proxies, context)
     87         return opener.open(url)
     88     else:
---> 89         return opener.open(url, data)
     90 def urlretrieve(url, filename=None, reporthook=None, data=None, context=None):
     91     global _urlopener

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\urllib.pyc in open(self, fullurl, data)
    213                 return getattr(self, name)(url)
    214             else:
--> 215                 return getattr(self, name)(url, data)
    216         except socket.error, msg:
    217             raise IOError, ('socket error', msg), sys.exc_info()[2]

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\urllib.pyc in open_https(self, url, data)
    441             if realhost: h.putheader('Host', realhost)
    442             for args in self.addheaders: h.putheader(*args)
--> 443             h.endheaders(data)
    444             errcode, errmsg, headers = h.getreply()
    445             fp = h.getfile()

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\httplib.pyc in endheaders(self, message_body)
   1047         else:
   1048             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1049         self._send_output(message_body)
   1050 
   1051     def request(self, method, url, body=None, headers={}):

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\httplib.pyc in _send_output(self, message_body)
    891             msg += message_body
    892             message_body = None
--> 893         self.send(msg)
    894         if message_body is not None:
    895             #message_body was not a string (i.e. it is a file) and

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\httplib.pyc in send(self, data)
    853         if self.sock is None:
    854             if self.auto_open:
--> 855                 self.connect()
    856             else:
    857                 raise NotConnected()

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\httplib.pyc in connect(self)
   1272 
   1273             self.sock = self._context.wrap_socket(self.sock,
-> 1274                                                   server_hostname=server_hostname)
   1275 
   1276     __all__.append("HTTPSConnection")

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\ssl.pyc in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    350                          suppress_ragged_eofs=suppress_ragged_eofs,
    351                          server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 352                          _context=self)
    353 
    354     def set_npn_protocols(self, npn_protocols):

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\ssl.pyc in __init__(self, sock, keyfile, certfile, server_side, cert_reqs, ssl_version, ca_certs, do_handshake_on_connect, family, type, proto, fileno, suppress_ragged_eofs, npn_protocols, ciphers, server_hostname, _context)
    577                         # non-blocking
    578                         raise ValueError("do_handshake_on_connect should not be specified for non-blocking sockets")
--> 579                     self.do_handshake()
    580 
    581             except (OSError, ValueError):

C:\Users\Nathan\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.6.2.3262.win-x86_64\lib\ssl.pyc in do_handshake(self, block)
    806             if timeout == 0.0 and block:
    807                 self.settimeout(None)
--> 808             self._sslobj.do_handshake()
    809         finally:
    810             self.settimeout(timeout)
```

Thanks a lot for your help!