# SSLError while pip installing

Tags: python, pip

Up until now I had no problems installing modules using pip. But I have been having an issue since a couple of weeks, whenever I try installing any module I get the following error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ephyviewer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ephyviewer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ephyviewer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ephyviewer/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))': /simple/ephyviewer/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/ephyviewer/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/ephyviewer/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)'))) - skipping
```

I have tried solutions suggested in other posts, like using the code:

```
pip install <package> --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org --proxy="<IP>:<port>"
```

But I always get the same error. I have also tried unistalling Python, pip, downgrading and upgrading it, and nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Means your SSL library is old and the site you are trying to reach won't accept it.

Comment: And how can I solve this?

Comment: What OS and version are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 Enterprise 64 bits

Comment: I'm confused.  Nothing wrong with pypi.org or Windows 10, but somehow your request gets there wrong.  Maybe you are going through a proxy?    SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER means you are requesting an unsupported version of SSL.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9963668/1216776

Comment: Ended up unistalling Python entirely and noticed I had it in two different locations, and that created some kind of confussion. After unistalling both and reinstalling it works again!